# Enum error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and

Tags: c#, enums

trying to compile this code but the if statement coughs up an error:

> Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and..

```
public enum ShoeType
{
    soccer = 0,
    jogging=1,
    fitness=2
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string shoetype = "1";

        if (Enum.Parse(typeof(ShoeType), shoetype) == ShoeType.jogging)
        {
            var test = "gotcha";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can see the `Enum.Parse` method is defined to return an `Object`, so you have to cast the result to the type you want. Like this:

```
(ShoeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ShoeType), shoetype)
```

You could also use the [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method and use the Boolean result to see if the parse was successful:

```
ShoeType type;
if (Enum.TryParse(shoetype, out type) && type == ShoeType.jogging)
{
    var test = "gotcha";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
if ( (ShoeType) Enum.Parse(typeof(ShoeType), shoetype) == ShoeType.jogging)
```